# Flutter - When using PersistentTabView, the appBar becomes persistent, too

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-packages

I'm using [Persistent Bottom Navigation Bar package](https://pub.dev/packages/persistent_bottom_nav_bar) and I have a problem. I have a home_page which holds 4 tabs (profile, favorites, search, genres) and a main App Bar for all of them. When I navigate from one of these tabs (favorites_page for example) to an inner page (movie_details_page), which has it's own App Bar with the movie name for title, the App Bar from home_page, navigates to movie_details_page, too. Is there a way to avoid this?

Here's my home_page Scaffold:

```
Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("MOVIEW"),
        elevation: 0,
      ),
      body: PersistentTabView(
        context,
        confineInSafeArea: true,
        screens: [
          GenresPage(),
          SearchPage(),
          ProfilePage(
            email: moview.email,
            password: moview.password,
            username: moview.username,
          ),
          FavoritesPage(),
        ],
        controller: _controller,
        items: [
          PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.grid_view),
            activeColorPrimary: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
            activeColorSecondary: Colors.white,
            inactiveColorPrimary: Colors.grey,
          ),
          PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.search_rounded),
            activeColorPrimary: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
            activeColorSecondary: Colors.white,
            inactiveColorPrimary: Colors.grey,
          ),
          PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.person),
            activeColorPrimary: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
            activeColorSecondary: Colors.white,
            inactiveColorPrimary: Colors.grey,
          ),
          PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.favorite_border_rounded),
            activeColorPrimary: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
            activeColorSecondary: Colors.white,
            inactiveColorPrimary: Colors.grey,
          ),
        ],
        popActionScreens: PopActionScreensType.all,
        itemAnimationProperties: ItemAnimationProperties(
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 450),
          curve: Curves.easeInOutQuart,
        ),
        screenTransitionAnimation: ScreenTransitionAnimation(
          animateTabTransition: true,
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 450),
          curve: Curves.easeInOutQuart,
        ),
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        hideNavigationBarWhenKeyboardShows: true,
        navBarStyle: NavBarStyle.style3,
      ),
    );
```

This is my favorite_page tab in home_page:

[image]

and this is movie_details_page:

[image]

PS: Please don't judge my UI :)

It's just for testing.

Answer (score 3):

Use

PersistentNavBarNavigator.pushNewScreen(
context,
screen: YourScreen(),
withNavBar: flase,
pageTransitionAnimation: PageTransitionAnimation.cupertino,
);

instead of

Navigator.push(
context,
MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => YourScreen()),
);

look at https://pub.dev/packages/persistent_bottom_nav_bar#navigator-functions

Answer (score 0):

I have never used of  `Persistent Bottom Navigation Bar` but In general in controller exist some prob like `selectedIndex` to get index of pages

```
class CustomWidgetExample extends StatefulWidget {
  final BuildContext menuScreenContext;
  CustomWidgetExample({Key key, this.menuScreenContext}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CustomWidgetExampleState createState() => _CustomWidgetExampleState();
}

class _CustomWidgetExampleState extends State<CustomWidgetExample> {
  PersistentTabController _controller;
  bool _hideNavBar;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = PersistentTabController(initialIndex: 0);
    _hideNavBar = false;
  }

  List<Widget> _buildScreens() {
    return [
      MainScreen(
        menuScreenContext: widget.menuScreenContext,
        hideStatus: _hideNavBar,
        onScreenHideButtonPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            _hideNavBar = !_hideNavBar;
          });
        },
      ),
      MainScreen(
        menuScreenContext: widget.menuScreenContext,
        hideStatus: _hideNavBar,
        onScreenHideButtonPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            _hideNavBar = !_hideNavBar;
          });
        },
      ),
      MainScreen(
        menuScreenContext: widget.menuScreenContext,
        hideStatus: _hideNavBar,
        onScreenHideButtonPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            _hideNavBar = !_hideNavBar;
          });
        },
      ),
      MainScreen(
        menuScreenContext: widget.menuScreenContext,
        hideStatus: _hideNavBar,
        onScreenHideButtonPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            _hideNavBar = !_hideNavBar;
          });
        },
      ),
      MainScreen(
        menuScreenContext: widget.menuScreenContext,
        hideStatus: _hideNavBar,
        onScreenHideButtonPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            _hideNavBar = !_hideNavBar;
          });
        },
      ),
    ];
  }

  List<PersistentBottomNavBarItem> _navBarsItems() {
    return [
      PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.home),
        title: "Home",
        activeColorPrimary: Colors.blue,
        inactiveColorPrimary: Colors.grey,
      ),
      PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.search),
        title: ("Search"),
        activeColorPrimary: Colors.teal,
        inactiveColorPrimary: Colors.grey,
      ),
      PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.add),
        title: ("Add"),
        activeColorPrimary: Colors.deepOrange,
        inactiveColorPrimary: Colors.grey,
      ),
      PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
        title: ("Settings"),
        activeColorPrimary: Colors.indigo,
        inactiveColorPrimary: Colors.grey,
      ),
      PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
        title: ("Settings"),
        activeColorPrimary: Colors.indigo,
        inactiveColorPrimary: Colors.grey,
      ),
    ];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Navigation Bar Demo')),
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              const Text('This is the Drawer'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: PersistentTabView.custom(
        context,
        controller: _controller,
        screens: _buildScreens(),
        confineInSafeArea: true,
        itemCount: 5,
        handleAndroidBackButtonPress: true,
        stateManagement: true,
        hideNavigationBar: _hideNavBar,
        screenTransitionAnimation: ScreenTransitionAnimation(
          animateTabTransition: true,
          curve: Curves.ease,
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
        ),
        customWidget: CustomNavBarWidget(
          items: _navBarsItems(),
          onItemSelected: (index) {
            setState(() {
              _controller.index = index; // THIS IS CRITICAL!! Don't miss it!
// you can use here to change appbar title or rebuild widget
            });
          },
          selectedIndex: _controller.index,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried your approach, but didn't achieve what I wanted. In onItemSelected function, you can change the state if you tap on an item; But I want to change the state, when user taps on a Movie or TV Show. I tried to change the appBar title when user taps on a Movie Card, but it doesn't change immediately.